# Can't load wikitude monotouch binding

Tags: ios, binding, xamarin.ios

The monotouch binding that I created for the [*Wikitude* SDK](http://www.wikitude.com/developer/download-sdk/) framework does not work at run time. I created my binding by following these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13070064/42826.

When I try to instantiate my wrapper class at run-time, I get the following exception:

> Wrapper type 'Wikitude.WTArchitectView' is missing its native
>   ObjectiveC class 'WTArchitectView'.

It looks like the native class **WTArchitectView** goes not get loaded by the binding assembly at run-time. The native library **WikitudeSDK.a** is indeed located in the binding assembly with the **ObjcBindingNativeLibrary** build action.

Here is my **LinkWith** declaration (notice the **-ObjC** that is [required](http://www.wikitude.com/developer/get-started/ios/) by the *Wikitude* native library):

```
[assembly: LinkWith ("WikitudeSDK.a", LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.Simulator, Frameworks = "CoreVideo Security SystemConfiguration CoreMedia AVFoundation CFNetwork CoreLocation CoreMotion MediaPlayer OpenGLES QuartzCore CoreGraphics", ForceLoad = true, LinkerFlags = "-ObjC", IsCxx = true)]
```

Most of my **ApiDefinition.cs** was created using ***[Objective Sharpie](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_libraries/objective_sharpie)***. 
*Note: I only left a single function for testing purposes.*

```
namespace Wikitude
{
    [BaseType (typeof (UIView))]
    interface WTArchitectView {

        [Export ("initializeWithKey:motionManager:")]
        void InitializeWithKey (string key, NSObject motionManager);
    }
}
```

Here is the ***Wikitude* SDK header file**: http://pastebin.com/HKBED11u

My project has the **ARMv7 + ARMv7s** supported architectures.

Do I have to force loading the native library somehow or did I simply miss something obvious to get the wrapper to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LinkWith` attribute only mention `ArmV7` and `Simulator` as `LinkTarget`s. If your device is `Armv7s`, this could explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason as soon as I changed the supported platform I started to see linking errors with the native lib, which explains why it would not load. My test phone is a iPhone 4 (Armv7).