# How to create binding Obj-c library to MonoMac from a framework

Tags: xamarin, monomac

For my project I have to interact with a device on mac.
The constructor provides me an objective-c framework : header file + binary file without extension
I would like to create a  binding library from this framework for MonoMac.

I've been reading theses  articles on binding Obj-C libraries to MonoTouch:

- http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_libraries
- [How to create a MonoTouch binding from a .framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586342/how-to-create-a-monotouch-binding-from-a-framework)

... but I can't find the same template of binding a project for MonoMac.

I used Sharpie provided  by Xamarin to generate my API definition with  Mac OS as target, so it seems ok for that point.

I think I have to rename my framework binary file as libXXXXX.a like for MonoTouch as said in the articles.

So now I'm looking for a kind of binding project template for MonoMac in order to generate my dll for Mac OS.

By the way i've succeed to generate a binding dll for  MonoTouch from my  Mac OS framework and reference it on basic iOS application for testing.
But as expected I ve en error at runtime. Mac OS framework probably not working with iOS i can understand that.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you check this article: http://brendanzagaeski.appspot.com/xamarin/0002.html